# Proxy-Authorization: Basic header fails for HTTPS

Tags: c#, http-headers, webbrowser-control

```
var credentialStringValue = user + ":" + pass;
var credentialByteArray = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentialStringValue);
var credentialBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(credentialByteArray);
string authObject = string.Format("Proxy-Authorization: Basic {0}{1}", credentialBase64String, Environment.NewLine);

System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser _WebBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();

_WebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com", string.Empty, null, authObject);
```

The code above is used to pass proxy credentials through to the .NET WebBrowser control. It works like a charm when going to normal HTTP URLs but when connecting to SSL it fails. What is the reason and is there a better alternative to this where SSL works?

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't what you are looking for, but have you considered using `HttpWebRequest` to do this task? `HttpWebRequest` can employ a `WebProxy` that supports using `NetworkCredentials` so you don't have to mess around with headers.

If you need `WebBrowser` control to display the page, perhaps just use it for that. Use `HttpWebRequest` to do the actual transfers and render the content in `WebBrowser`.

For Reference: [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) & [WebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.aspx)